# Facebook and Salesforce SSO

Tags: community, single-sign-on, identity, facebook

We are implementing Salesforce and Facebook SSO integration for communities. Do anyone know how to handle the registration process when the Facebook user signed up for facebook by using the mobile number instead of Email? Any pointers will be helpful.